# How to set a type of an array in an anonymous Object

Tags: typescript

How do I set the type of the array, because `grid: []: number[]` wont work

```
const game = {
  sizeX: 9,
  sizeY: 5,
  SCALE: 80,
  grid: [],  //Object literal's property 'grid' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
  money: 600,
}
```

Comment: `grid: [] as number[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type the whole object: (This is strongly recommended)

```
interface Game {
  sizeX: number
  sizeY: number
  SCALE: number
  grid: number[]
}

const game: Game = {
  sizeX: 9,
  sizeY: 5,
  SCALE: 80,
  grid: [],
  money: 600,
}
```

Or you can cast the empty array:

```
grid: [] as number[]
```

Or you can make the array non empty:

```
grid: [123]
```

To name a few

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to use a variable (typed) to put your array, and than use it :

```js
const grid: number[] = [];

const game = {
  sizeX: 9,
  sizeY: 5,
  SCALE: 80,
  grid,
  money: 600,
};
```